# Sony Vaio Pro 13 (SVP13212SGBI) can no longer run when mains is not connected

Tags: linux, laptop, battery, sony-vaio

I bought this laptop brand new [in February this year](http://tshepang.net/sony-vaio-pro-13-svp13212sgbi), and only in the last week or so has it started showing this brokenness. The degradation was somewhat gradual, since I was able to run the laptop only on battery power, and it would shut down at some point, even though battery indicator was far from empty. But now it's not even turning on at all on battery power, and it shuts down immediately when I remove mains.

Running **`acpi`**, I sometimes get:

> Battery 0: Charging, 99%, charging at zero rate - will never fully charge.

And sometimes:

> Battery 0: Charging, 99%, 00:19:41 until charged

Could this output be wrong, claiming 99% when the battery is nowhere near that?

Comment: How old is the battery?

Comment: I bought the laptop brand new in February.

Comment: If you bought it in February it should still be under warranty.

Comment: @DanielRHicks thanks, I just contacted the store I got it from.

Comment: Open up "VAIO Control Center" or whatever and see if there are some battery-related options there.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the little cover on the back of the laptop, there's a connector and a square black button. push the button with a pen for at least 1 full second.

boot the computer while connected to the power supply. it should work.

Note that its normal for the battery to stop charging at 99% for a while then charge again. it never reaches 100%. thats the battery saving algorithm.

as for the reason why the laptop shutdowns/cant start, ask sony - i never got a proper reply. the button thing works as work around.